# Python, PySerial and cx-freeze

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, cx-freeze

Trying to learn cx-freeze. I have a python program that I am trying freeze to exe.

I use PySerial and no matter how I try to include win32 nothing seems to help. I use Python 3.2 and win7.

I have searched the web thin, and others have had the same problem, but no solution seems to be appearing. But I doubt that no one have succeeded in cx_freezing something that uses PySerial.

I am completely stuck. Any help would be much appreciated

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\
7, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "snapper.py", line 8, in
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\
    from serial.serialwin32 import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\
e>
    from serial import win32
ImportError: cannot import name win32
```

Setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['caml.pkl', 'seql.pkl']
includes = ['DataBase', 'serial.win32']
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = []

setup(
    name = 'Setup',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Snapper configuration utility',
    author = 'LST',
    author_email = 'info@-.com',
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('snapper.py')]
)
```

Any idea where to go from here?
Thanks in advance

I tried to do a blind import:

```
if False:
   import serial.win32
```

no luck...

Maybe i am looking at this the wrong way....

Comment: what if you change the include to `serial`?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, problem solved.

You need to use packages to force cx_Freeze to include serial.win32 (not "include")

Following line works:

```
packages = ['serial.win32']
```

Memo to my self and others: Be sure to check the dist folder for actually included packages. I have no idea why all packages didn't get included by cx_Freeze in the first place, but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a different tool to freeze your program, [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) says it supports PySerial.

Comment: PyInstaller looks really nice. But does not support python 3.x as far as I can see

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not sure how I failed to notice the python3 tag.

Comment: No problem. I am new to Python and I fail to see how I just didn't start with 2.7 :-) might go down that road soon though...

Comment: Okay, problem solved. I'm a newbie... admitted. 

You need to use packages to force CX_Freeze to include serial.win32 (not "includes")

Following line works:

    packages = ['serial.win32']

Thanks